# At what time control do you stop recording your moves?

Tags: tournament, notation

I've been to a 15|2 (Fischer) tournament where it was not necessary to record your moves and I've also played in longer games where it was expected. My question is at what time limit are you no longer expected to record your games (generally speaking)?

More specifically, would you expect to have to record your moves in a G30 tournament?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything less than or equal to G/29 does not require you to record moves, according to USCF. Otherwise known as Blitz and Quick, they have a separate rating for those time controls.

Reference: [An Introduction to
USCF-Rated Tournaments](http://archive.uschess.org/ratings/info/intro.pdf) [PDF]

So, yes, you do need to record your moves in a G/30, because that is considered Standard time control.

There is a rule that allows you to stop recording once you (or your opponent) have less than 5 minutes on the clock, in Standard time control games. See #7: [USCF - FIDE Rule Differences - 2 Columns](http://main.uschess.org/content/view/11750/668/)

Additionally, if you have an increment of 30 seconds or more, it looks like you have to record moves regardless of the time left on the clock. (I wonder if people really have that sort of increment in tournaments.)

Comment: Yes, some tournaments do have a 30 second increment throughout. For instance, from the regulations of the 2012 Tal Memorial: "The rate of play is 1 hour 40 minutes for 40 moves plus 50 minutes for 20 moves plus 15 minutes for the rest of the game with a 30 second increment per move, starting from the first."

Comment: Wow, that would make for some long games. I guess it makes sense for high end tournaments where you don't want to see someone lose because they blundered while out of time.

Comment: One more point, the tournament organizer can always announce *different rules* so long as they are announced far enough in advance.  I have played in one G/30 tournament that did not require notating per the decision of the organizer, but this is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: In Europe 90min + 30min after 40 and 30s Increment from move 1 is a common tc in tournaments.

Answer (score 3):

I always write my moves down even in 30 minute games; I get funny looks, but I can record 3/4 of the game before the position deems otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

My memory is a lot better than my handwriting. I just do the best I can and try to fix it after the game. I will say though that anything over 30 minutes a side and Im not worried about time. I may even get up and wander around, go to the bathroom, or look for a food truck etc..